# Adding double quotes to last field of ls command output

Tags: bash, unix, scripting, sed, awk

I was writing a shell script , where it will look for files(ZIP) in a directory using ls command and unzip them in destination , the problem is that the file name is having spaces between ,so when script is scanning it considering only name after space

Example: if File name is "a b c.zip" , only c.zip is considered to be file name and then it say file not found.

So please let me know how to handle this

i thought if i can enclose the file name in double quotes it should work.so i was looking how can i add the double quote to last field of ls command .
i need all the field of ls command since i am checking for file size and timestamp as well before unzip ,so i need to enclose only file name with double quotes which is the last field of ls command.

Regards,
Sathya

Comment: What about `ls -1 | awk '{printf("%s%s%s\n","\"",$0,"\"")}'`?

Comment: You cannot reliably parse the output of ls. You need to use the approach @clarkw suggests or `find . -maxdepth1 ...` with `-exec` or `...-print0 | xargs -0`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you use Bash's *wildcard patterns* (which would deal with white spaces for you) to get the file list and then use the `stat` command to get info about a specific file. For example:

```
$ ls -l
total 1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 2013-03-25 16:27 a b c.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 2013-03-25 16:27 d e f.txt
$ for file in *.txt; do stat "$file"; done
  File: `a b c.txt'
  Size: 0               Blocks: 1          IO Block: 131072 regular empty file
Device: 3dd0002h/64815106d      Inode: 455629      Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2013-03-25 16:27:35.388291856 +0800
Modify: 2013-03-25 16:27:35.388291856 +0800
Change: 2013-03-25 16:27:35.388310939 +0800
  File: `d e f.txt'
  Size: 0               Blocks: 1          IO Block: 131072 regular empty file
Device: 3dd0002h/64815106d      Inode: 455630      Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2013-03-25 16:27:35.388401772 +0800
Modify: 2013-03-25 16:27:35.388401772 +0800
Change: 2013-03-25 16:27:35.388412772 +0800
$
```

Note that `stat` has a `--format` option so you can tell it to give you only the info you are interested in about the files.